# Points to line accuracy concerns in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, accuracy, points-to-line

I have a csv of a GPS trace with lat-longs that I want to convert into a line so I can measure the distance. My workflow was as follows:

1) Import csv into ArcMap 10.4

2) Convert latlongs to points and create a feature file

3) Use points to line tool in the Data Management toolbox to draw a line from the points (the points are in sequence and have unique IDs)

4) Measure the length of the line feature by calculating geometry.

The csv had 277 points; the calculated length of the line feature after step 4 was ~21 km. However, when I do the same calculation using other software (e.g. using geodist command in stata) or by manually measuring the distance between the points (using the ruler tool in ArcMap), this distance comes out to be ~18 km. I cannot figure out why this discrepancy is occurring. At some places, the points are overlapping (as shown in image below), but I would expect this to results in higher estimation of distance when measuring as distance between points compared to the length of the line, and not a lower one as is currently. Can someone provide insight as to why I am getting this discrepancy? As of now it seems the points measure (18 km) is the correct one and not the 21 km one. Why is the line length feature not showing the right results?

[image: Some overlapping points with line feature cutting through]

Comment: Remove duplicate points and repeat workflow. Perhaps your line goes backwards.

Comment: Is the line feature class also in lat-lon?

Comment: @FelixIP the points are in sequence and I have looked closely at the points and the line and it does not go backward. Its a trace of a moving vehicle so I don't think that's it.

Comment: @mkennedy I am not sure what you mean by that question. The line is a feature class with a single row in the attribute table with three columns: "FID", "Shape", "Id". I added a 'length' column. Another point to note is that I projected the line to WGS 84 mercator projection before I could do the calculation of length.

Comment: It will take less time to test my suggestion, than typing your reply to it.

Comment: Yes :) I am trying it out right now.

Comment: I tried the 'Find identical' and 'Delete identical' tools and found no duplicates. Should I be trying something else?

Comment: Upload somewhere and let me know projection.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. Mercator can wildly distort distance--it's not designed for distance calculations. You don't have an option to calc the geodesic distance? That will match the other software. What ArcGIS version?

Comment: A bit of a long shot, but on converting the CSV to points, try defining the projection to a Geographic Projection, then re-project the points to "Projected" or metre projection before converting to line. Maybe try a UTM projection and see if that helps? Do you know that the 18km is definitely correct?

Comment: @FelixIP apologies for the delay; had something personal occupy me. The link is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bhjb7czfjm7as1/GNZ_distance.csv?dl=0.

Comment: @mkennedy and Keagen Allan since this is gps data obtained from smart phone; I wasn't sure what the ideal projection would be so relied on standard WGS1984. This data is in Pakistan so UTM42N could be an option. When I convert the csv to points, projection is undefined so I defined it to WGS1984 before converting to line. Then I projected it to Projected WGS1984 Mercator project to get distance in meters. 21 km is from this projection. The 18 km estimate is based on geodesic calculation. Which would would you say is more accurate?

Comment: Also I have arcgis version 10.4

Comment: @mkennedy I tried a UTM projection and that seems to have solved it! I am still a beginner so didn't realize how much different changing the projection would make! Many thanks.